# Breakpoint shifted when file gets updated

Tags: visual-studio-2005, breakpoints

I am using visual studio 2005 for my windows application developed in C#.
I have kept few breakpoints in the class,when i update the svn,these breakpoints get shifted(Actually remain in same line no and not in the method where it is intended to).Is there a way we can update the break point as well?

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints are stored in your suo file and that file is not human readable.  There is no way to change this.

Comment: Isnt there a way to update the file?I mean create a event on class file change and update this suo file?

Comment: No. The file is stored in binary format and is saved when you save the solution. Here is a link with more information:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Are you storing the SUO file in source control?

Comment: no it is not.Isnt there an event on file update in visual studio?where in these two files can be compared and breakpoints shifted using a hook script?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you can do.  I have never had this problem.  I found these links. I'm not sure how much help they'll be:
1) http://intuitlabs.com/apps/breakpoint-analyzer-for-microsoft-visual-studio   2) http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/07/21/debugger-settings-visual-studio-add-in-easily-copy-breakpoints-between-machines.aspx